# How to use Box2D javascript without using the inbuilt debugdraw?

Tags: javascript, box2d

Lets say I want to use Box2D javascript to simply print the coordinates of a falling object, into a text box, and not simulate the scene using debugDraw.

Or,
Lets say I want to use Box2D javascript to simulate it to a canvas using WebGL or some other library, and not simulate the scene using debugDraw.

I looked at many tutorials (including Seth's) and they all show us how to simulate the physics using debugDraw.

Is there some way where I can get access to each body's positional coordinates, angles, velocities, etc. ? Maybe all those parameters that will enable me to create a simulation of my own and not from debugDraw.

Thanks!

Comment: Which JavaScript version of box2d are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some research I found that the [documentation](http://www.kyucon.com/doc/box2d/) here contains methods and members such as `m_position`, `GetAngle()`, `GetBodyList()` which return information about the parameters of a body, with which it can rendered using a graphics library like WebGL.

Comment: Yeah, that's what you should do.